# English content on an RTL site

Tags: rtl

**Background**

We have a client who has a group of websites, one per country. Each site is translated into the local languages, some of which are RTL languages (e.g.: Arabic).

These websites are fully localised, including headers, footers, navigation and other page furniture as well as page content.

However, we have a client requirement to add a recruitment section to each country's site. The recruitment section will be centralised, with each country's site sharing the content and not translated. That is it will only available in English language. The rationale here is that the primary language used to communicate within the organisation is English, so any potential candidate must have a very good level of English and thus the recruitment section itself acts as a screener to ensure this. (This is not something we are able to challenge.)

**My question**

The question I have is on the RTL site, where everything is right-aligned, how should we display with the English copy? Should it be left-aligned, or would you still align it to the right, even though you would read this part of the page from left to right?

I hope that all makes sense. It's tricky to articulate the problem without a visual example... I had a look through several arabic sites to see how the handle it but they all seem to be completely in Arabic (sensibly enough).

Any ideas, or even links to other sites that handle this type of scenario well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If all the sites share the same content, The link to recruitment in various languages can just link to the recruitment page on the english version of the site. One example of a company that took this route is google. If you are on google.es or another language version of google but click on the recruiting link, which is in spanish, you are sent to google.com/about/careers rather than a foreign language page. This avoids the issue of having text in both languages on one page altogether.

Comment: That's a really valid point, thanks. Might go back to the client with that proposition but I'm expecting them to push back and demand mirrored content on each site. They're not comfortable with users/potential customers moving between country sites as it messes up the way they handle lead gens, preferring to pretty much ring fence users within a country's site (even though these types of users are not actually their customers). I'll put it to them, and also stress SEO benefits of not duplicating content, but it might not be enough. Thanks for the idea and ammunition though :)